# Is it possible to connect to a Firebase Database to a different Firebase Project?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have two android apps (A and B) and both have separate projects on Firebase, Currently I am working on a feature which would lets me send messages between app A and app B  using FCM. Due to both apps being in different projects, I am unable to do this and It is not possible to put both the apps on a single project due to some other reason.

So I was thinking if I could create a messages table in app A and access the same from app B and implement my messaging feature. Is it possible to do this? if yes, can you please give me some info? if no is there an alternative?

thanks

Comment: no it is not possible because package name of there projects are different!! and config file also different

Comment: Firebase is 1:1. you should do that, A would be the sender, and B the receiver.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to access the "other" database by explicitly providing the configuration data:

```
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
        .setApiKey("AI...j0")
        .setApplicationId("1:5...e0") // I'm not certain this is needed
        .setDatabaseUrl("https://myapp.firebaseio.com")
        .build();
FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(getApplicationContext(), options, "app");
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(app);
```

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen: Is it possible to do the same access from Cloud Functions too?