# How to use same google-service.json file in multiple android firebase projects?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-push-notification

I want to use google-service.json file in multiple project, is it possible to use same google-service.json in multiple projects? if possible how can we do it?

Comment: I think it is not possible because when you create a new project on Firebase it asks you to provide the package name of an android project then after you can download the google-service.json file contain information about that project

Comment: ok, according to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39366056/is-it-possible-to-connect-to-a-firebase-database-to-a-different-firebase-project we can share the database but what about json file??

Comment: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/organizing-your-firebase-enabled-android-app-builds.html

Comment: can we send push notification to app which has shared database?

Comment: can we use multiple firebase json file in one android application as i want to use diffrent database for single app based on user select ? it is posible?

Answer (score 1):

You can add different apps in same firebase project.
You can share same database of different apps in same project.

Comment: ok, can we send push notification to app which has shared database?

Comment: yes firebase provides a various features to know more check documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/?authuser=0